# Dynamics 365 - A check to ensure that all tasks have been complete

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a scenario where the user wants a check in place to ensure that all tasks have been completed before moving onto next stage on the Business Process Flow.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways to achieve it.

Option 1: Create a bool field - `Tasks closed?` & keep that in BPF step, if it’s true then platform will also users to move forward. Otherwise not.

You can mark this as [read-only](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2015/08/applying-scripts-on-business-process-flow-controls-in-dynamics-crm-2015/), write a plugin on Task completion to update this as `yes`, when there is no more open tasks.

[Read more](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2017/05/stage-gating-a-business-process-flow-using-two-options-attribute-type-in-dynamics-365-customer-engagement/)

Option 2: Can have a js validation onStageChange or onSave to retrieve open child tasks, check the count, show notification & preventDefault.

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/277316)

You can do the same in pre-update plugin, throw `InvalidPluginExecutionException` if there are open tasks.